# Bitbucket Git - Understanding the diff between two branches in a pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Say that a pull request is created in bit bucket to merge branch-2 into branch-1. The pull request has a diff tab to show the difference between these branches. I'd like to know the order of the comparison in the diff tab. Is it like git branch-1 branch-2, OR is it git branch-2 branch-1 ? Thanks.

Comment: Also refer - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Understanding-the-diff-between-two-branches-in-a-pull-request/qaq-p/1206332#M48385

Answer (score 1):

The diff you are seeing in Bitbucket will represent the changes which would be introduced into the *target* branch from the source branch which is being merged.  To be specific, for some source file, you would be looking at the version of that file in `branch-1` with the diff/changes corresponding to what the `branch-2` version did to the same file.

In general, you would not have the situation where both the remote `branch-1` and `branch-2` are both ahead of some common commit.  Rather, in this situation, usually Bitbucket would force you to update your local `branch-2` with changes from the upstream `branch-1` before allowing the pull request to happen.